# I have been involved in art/arts/the arts

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Let's say I did music, dancing and acting in my life. Can I use these three words interchangeably?  I think I probably can.

- I have been involved in art.
- I have been involved in arts.
- I have been involved in the arts.

I looked at the definitions on collinsdictionary.com but I am not completely sure if we can say these sentences interchangeably. What do you think, and would there be a British-American difference?

Comment: Were the definitions of "art" and "arts" identical? Please include the links and the definitions in your question.

Comment: This is one of those rare occasions where I'd like to be able to vote to migrate a question from ELL to ELU rather than the other way around. See [**What is the difference, if any, between 'art', 'the arts', and 'Art'?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28762/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-art-the-arts-and-art) as asked on ELU before this ELL sister site even existed.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you have been involved in ***the arts.***

*The arts* [refers to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_arts) the general set of fields of which artistic/creative expression is a major part (such as writing, theatre, dance, painting, illustration, architecture, fashion, and many others).

*Art*, on the other hand, tends to refer to the creations of the artist, whether that is a painting, a play, a book, a sculpture, etc.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/art) gives the essential meaning of "art" as, in relevant part:

> something that is created with imagination and skill and that is beautiful or that expresses important ideas or feelings

or

> works created by artists : paintings, sculptures, etc., that are created to be beautiful or to express important ideas or feelings."

It can also refer to the "methods or skills" used to create such works (e.g., *He studied art in college.*)

"involved in arts" sounds incorrect to me—I would avoid this phrasing.

---

Note: I am a native American English speaker, so my answer is largely from that perspective.  I have not encountered a difference in this area with British English, but my experience with BrE is limited.

Comment: Same for British English https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arts

Comment: Thank you. What is the exact reason you wouldn't use, "arts," without the article?